# Loading Safe Cached Image through HttpRequest

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I've been searching for two hours how to fix this:

In Angular 8.2.6, for some image caching reasons, I need to add a header through an HTTP Interceptor, and therefore I need to request the image through a HTTP Request:

```
this.http.get('ttps://1048665290.rsc.cdn77.org/thumbnails/MY-60-B.jpg', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
   .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(typeof res);
        const blob = new Blob([res]);
        this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
   });
```

Everything seems fine, but for some reason the type of the result is an Object instead of an ArrayBuffer or Blob, therefore there's a code in @angular/HttpClient that throws an Error:

```
case 'arraybuffer':
    return res$.pipe(map(function (res) {
        // Validate that the body is an ArrayBuffer.
        if (res.body !== null && !(res.body instanceof ArrayBuffer)) {
            throw new Error('Response is not an ArrayBuffer.');
        }
        return res.body;
    }));
case 'blob':
    return res$.pipe(map(function (res) {
        // Validate that the body is a Blob.
        if (res.body !== null && !(res.body instanceof Blob)) {
            throw new Error('Response is not a Blob.');
        }
        return res.body;
    }));
case 'text':
    return res$.pipe(map(function (res) {
        // Validate that the body is a string.
        if (res.body !== null && typeof res.body !== 'string') {
            throw new Error('Response is not a string.');
        }
        return res.body;
    }));
```

So... the matter is: **How can I load it without getting this error?**

Because I don't know **how to transform Text version of image/jpeg to ArrayBuffer or to Blob.**

**May the problem be in the CDN Server?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you specify `responseType` as `blob` directly?

Comment: @David Because the `response` of the Observable is also an Object, which returns the error "Response is not a Blob."

Comment: I assume that the missing `h` in your `ttps://...` url is not in your real code, right?

Comment: @David Yup is not the real code heh, I changed to that for an example, as the real code is an array, and with that code you can test it anywhere.